# A base for the kernel of a definite integral?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The problem is this:

> Let $P_2$ be the vectorspace of polynomials of degree $2$ or less. Let
>   $\int:$ $P_2$ → $\mathbb{R}$ be the function given by $\int(p)$ = $\int_0^1p(t)dt$
>
> Give a base for the kernel (null space) to $\int$.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around functions (or polynomials) as vectors. From what I understand $\int$ is a linear transformation an the kernel is the solution to $\int(p)=0$. 
 If $p=ax^2+bx+c$ then $\int(p)=0=\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}+c$ 
 Is this the kernel? How to go from this to a base for the kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's instructive to invoke the isomorphism of the polynomial-vector space and $\mathbb R^3$ given by $\Phi:ax^2+bx+c\mapsto \pmatrix{a\\b\\c}$. Then the matrix-representation of the integral in the basis $\{\Phi(x^2),\Phi(x),\Phi(1)\}$ is 
$$\Phi\int\Phi^{-1} = (\tfrac 1 3,\tfrac 1 2,1)$$
So we've reduced the question to finding a basis for the kernel of the linear functional given by the row-vector $(\tfrac 1 3,\tfrac 1 2,1)$. As you noted, this kernel is given by all $(a,b,c)^T\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $\frac a 3+\frac b 2+c=0$. This equation is solved e.g. by all vectors of the form $\pmatrix{a\\b\\-\frac a 3-\frac b 2}$, so one possible basis is 
$$\left\{ \pmatrix{1\\0\\-\frac 1 3},\pmatrix{0\\1\\-\frac 1 2} \right\}.$$
Applying $\Phi^{-1}$ to this basis we obtain the set
$$\left\{ x^2-\tfrac 1 3 \;,\;x-\tfrac 1 2  \right\}$$
as a basis for the kernel of $\int$.